# Python 3.x functools.partial() function got multiple values for argument parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I am trying to pass an extra argument to map function for a Django REST framework API endpoint. The following worked in my test, but I am not sure what am I missing in my Django API.

```
>>> tt

[(datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 10, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 1, 0, 0))]

>>> def t(d1: datetime.datetime, d2: datetime.datetime, i: int):
...  print(f"First: {d1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} & Second: {d2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} w/ ID: {i}")

>>> list(map(partial(t, i=10), *tt))
First: 2023-04-01 & Second: 2023-04-10 w/ ID: 10
First: 2023-04-10 & Second: 2023-04-01 w/ ID: 10
[None, None]
```

But the similar apporach does not seem to work in my API in views.py

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def get_registration_counts(request, start: str, stop: str) -> Response:
    date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    # validations to make sure start and stop parameters are valid, else return HTTP 400
    datasets = []
    def get_counts(d1: datetime.datetime, d2: datetime.datetime, id: int) -> int:
        r = Entity.object.filter(some_date__gte=d1, some_date__lte=d2, fk_id=id);
        c = r.count()
        return c
    # calculate date range
    dates = [(some_start_date1, some_end_date1), (some_start_date2, some_end_date2)]
    some_values = OtherEntity.objects.filter(active=1).values("id", "name")
    for v in some_values:
        counts = list(map(functools.partial(get_counts, id=v["id"]), *dates) # error
        datasets.append(counts)
        ...
    ...
```

Returns following error

**ERROR**

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: get_counts() got multiple values for argument 'id'

**EDIT:**

I do know, I could use list comprehension, but I woud like to understand if I am missing something.

Comment: This looks okay on the surface, but that error would appear if the `dates` list grows beyond two elements. Is there any modification of `dates` in the `for` loop?

Comment: No modification, after creating a pair of dates.

Comment: Please include the full error message, including the line of the error